# How to print a large collection of images from IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a large collection (let's say **50**) images, which are **1-bit PNGs** of roughly the size **2500x3500** pixels. Filesize per image is about **50KB**. I want to print these images straight from my website.

I have a page which shows all these 50 images at once and a button to print all images on this page. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but IE11 runs into serious memory problems. Turns out each image needs more than **30MB** when IE11 renders them (32-bit??) and IE11 soon runs into it's internal memory limit of **1GB**.

I can't show smaller images either, because the print functionality prints exactly those elements that are shown on the page, and smaller images would look bad once printed out.

How can I print all full-size images or conveniently download them with the press of a button?

Comment: Can you please try to post a sample code so that we can see how actually you are trying to print the PNG images. It can help us to make a test with IE 11 and produce the issue. Without any code example we are not able to provide any accurate suggestion. Thanks for your understanding.